# Find the degree of remaining verticies

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

A simple graph G has 7 vertices and 9 edges. The degrees of some of its vertices
are 2, 2, 4, 2. Furthermore, G is known to have an Euler circuit.
Find the degrees of the remaining vertices, and draw a picture of G

How can i do this? I'm very tired so clear instruction would be great!

What I have done:
To find degrees of the remaining verticies
= $2*9$
=18 therefore remaining degrees = $18-10 = 8$

Since G is a Euler circuit the degrees must be even. Therefore 3 remaining verticies must have a degree of 2, 2 and 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hints:**

- By the Handshaking Lemma, the sum of the degrees of the remaining vertices is $8$.
- Since $G$ has an Euler circuit, all vertices must have a strictly positive even degree.

Comment: Any tips on how to go about drawing this bad boy?

Comment: Have you figured out the exact degrees of the $3$ remaining vertices?

Comment: Would they be v1 deg2, v2 deg 2 and v3 deg 4?

Comment: Correct! Now to draw the graph, just mess around for a bit. Start by drawing $7$ vertices arranged in a circle. Label two of them to have degree $4$. Now try a greedy algorithm: draw the edges of the degree $4$ vertices first. Continue adding more edges until each vertex has the correct degree.